# Passenger Records Research for India

Tags: immigration, records, india, aden

I am researching my family tree.
I am looking for an ancestor who came by **ship** while working for the **British**.

I am not aware of the ship name he came on. He was approximately **born** in **1835 +/- 40 years** in **Mumbai (**formerly known as Bombay**), India**.

Where can I find passenger records for **native Indians** who immigrated from **Mumbai** (**formerly known as Bombay**), **India**, to **Aden Colony, Yemen**, in the **1850s** +**/- 30 years**?

This was during the **British colonisation** of **India** and **Aden**.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be any passenger lists for that route or that general type of journey.

In general, lists were created for the benefit of the immigration authorities at the place of arrival. They mostly only exist for intercontinental journeys like England to America or Australia. I have never seen any for shorter journeys like Bombay to Aden, unless that part of a much longer voyage. Bombay to Aden under British rule was in effect a domestic journey and that presumably means that there may not have been any arrivals checks. So no passenger list required.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer.
Is there any place that I can look for domestic journey records for these countries online?
Would it be better for me to do research in Pakistan, India, and Aden?

Comment: Yes that’s a possibility but I wonder precisely what records may still exist, after 170 years or more. I doubt births were registered there in 1830 (that didn’t start in England till 1837). And Aden (modern Yemen is a ware zone just now. Not sure how you'll get on there).